# Vue.js 3 declare a props with Array of Class

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-props

I try to define my component props where type is Array

But it not working...

```
import { Person } from '...'
export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        people: Array<Person>
    }
})
```

```
export class Person {
...
}
```

How to declare it correctly ?

Answer (score 11):

use Proptype imported from 'vue'

```
import { Person } from '...'
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue';
    
export default defineComponent({
     props: {
        people: Array as PropType<Array<Person>>,
        default: undefined,
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

(Vue v3.0.4)

Use PropType:

```
import { Person } from '...'
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import type { PropType } from 'vue'
    
export default defineComponent({
     props: {
        people: Array as PropType<Array<Person>>,
        required: false,
        default: () => [],
     }
})
```

Ref: https://vuejs.org/api/utility-types.html#proptype-t

Answer (score -1):

Typeof a class is `function`. When declaring a function prop with options-api its required to have a default.

With composition-api you can do it like this:

```
import { Person } from '...';

const props = defineProps({
  people: Person
})
```

Alternative solution(options-api):

```
import { Person } from '...';

props: {
  people: {
    default: () => Person,
  },
},
```